# Add comments to the text generated by induct rule

Tags: isabelle

Currently, when using the induct rule, an automated goal split is generated:

for instance:

theorem example:

assumes a: "A"

assumes b: "B"

shows "A ∧ B"

proof (induct rule: conjI)

generates automatically the following text with the proof outline with cases to be
selected and pasted:

1. A
2. B

Proof outline with cases:

case 1

then show ?case sorry

next

case 2

then show ?case sorry

qed

Would it it be possible to generate the proof outline with **commented cases**
to be selected and pasted: For instance we would have:

1. A
2. B

Proof outline with cases:

case 1 (* A *)

then show ?case sorry

next

case 2 (* B *)

then show ?case sorry

qed

Thank you.

Mamoun

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to generate comments for cases without modifying Isabelle itself.
But you can change the name of the cases using `case_names` or `goal_cases`:

```
lemma myConjI[case_names left right]: 
  assumes a: "A"
  assumes b: "B"
  shows "A ∧ B"
  using assms by auto


theorem example1:
  assumes a: "A"
  assumes b: "B"
  shows "A ∧ B"
proof (induct rule: myConjI)
  case left
  then show ?case sorry
next
  case right
  then show ?case sorry
qed


theorem example2:
  assumes a: "A"
  assumes b: "B"
  shows "A ∧ B"
proof (rule conjI, goal_cases Bla Blub)
  case Bla
  then show ?case sorry
next
  case Blub
  then show ?case sorry
qed
```

Comment: Yet another variant: `proof (induct rule: conjI[case_names left right])`.

Comment: The names of the cases may be not meaningfull for reading the proof afterwards. Considering the TLA proof rule for weak fairness: expressed as follows:  |~ ?P ∧ _actrans ?N ?v ⟶ ○?P ∨ ○?Q ⟹
|~ ?P ∧ ⟨?N ∧ ?A⟩_?v ⟶ ○?Q ⟹
⊢ ?P ⟶ Enabled ⟨?A⟩_?v ⟹
|~ ?P ∧ Unchanged ?v ⟶ ○?P ⟹
⊢ □[?N]_?v ∧ WF(?A)_?v ⟶ ?P ↝ ?Q   The commented cases may be more meaningfull in order to read the full proof afterward.